# Extracting a value from Json object in C#

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have a Json document and I am trying to get the value for AnalogInput for each channel from 1 to 4. 
I have tried this code:

```
 JObject originalObject = JObject.Parse(testJsonObject);
 var analogInputTrueValues = originalObject.Descendants().OfType<JProperty>().Where(p => p.Name == "DigitalInput").Select(x => x.Value).ToArray();
```

where testJsonObject is the Json file that gets loaded by another method.

Debugging the code, the value for analogInputTrueValues is:

```
{Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken[4]}
    [0]: {13}
    [1]: {13}
    [2]: {14}
    [3]: {14}
```

,which is correct. but I am interested to have an array or a list like {"13","13","14","14"}. This is where I can not move forward since I can not extract those exact values and have them in a list or an array. 
Even when I do:

```
digitalInputTrueValues.GetValue(0)
{13}
    base: {13}
    HasValues: false
    Type: String
    Value: "13"
```

I can't extract the Value, which is what I am interested in. 
How can I get around this kind of problem and extract my desired values? 
The object that I am working with is as follows:

```
{
        "module": {
            "serial": "3",
            "label": "A",
            "lat": "B",
            "long": "C",
            "channels": [
{"channel": "1", "label": "Channel 1", "AnalogInput": "13", "AnalogInputRaw": "13", "AnalogInputScale": "Raw", "DigitalInput": "Off"},
{"channel": "2", "label": "Channel 2", "AnalogInput": "13", "AnalogInputRaw": "13", "AnalogInputScale": "Raw", "DigitalInput": "On"},
{"channel": "3", "label": "Channel 3", "AnalogInput": "14", "AnalogInputRaw": "14", "AnalogInputScale": "Raw", "DigitalInput": "On"},
{"channel": "4", "label": "Channel 4", "AnalogInput": "14", "AnalogInputRaw": "14", "AnalogInputScale": "Raw", "DigitalInput": "On"}
            ],
            "variables": [
             {"1": "0"},
             {"2": "0"},
             {"3": "1"},
             {"4": "0"}
            ]
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to include `ToString()` in your `Select` expression after `x.Value`:

```
JObject originalObject = JObject.Parse(json);
var analogInputTrueValues = originalObject.Descendants()
                                          .OfType<JProperty>()
                                          .Where(p => p.Name == "AnalogInput")
                                          .Select(x => x.Value.ToString())
                                          .ToArray();
```

Working example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/tU5Mc8

Alternative method using strongly-typed classes: https://dotnetfiddle.net/US4Bs0

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Is the way that I am extracting the AnalogInput value a good way? Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: Using LINQ-to-JSON, the way you are doing, is correct and good.  An alternative method would be to create strongly-typed classes corresponding to your JSON and then use `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject()` to deserialize the JSON into your classes.  It comes down to personal preference.

Comment: I added some fiddles to my answer so you can compare the difference between the two methods.  Using LINQ-to-JSON is much less code, but some people find the strongly typed classes easier to work with.